# ngOnChanges not firing if an @Input is receiving an object

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-template

Parent component template:

```html
<my-component [param]="whatever"></my-component>
```

Parent component code:

```json
whatever = { value1: 0, value2: 1, value3: 'foo' };
```

Child component code:

```js
@Input() public param: any;

ngOnChanges() {
  console.log('Received input: ', param);
}
```

This isn't working. Any change to `whatever` will be unnoticed by the child component and `ngOnChanges` won't fire.

It also doesn't work if I try to use a setter:

```js
@Input() set param(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

And it doesn't help if I try to run a manual zone update in the parent component.

Apparently `@Input()` can only detect when an object's structure has changed, but not its values.

So how can I pass an object as an `@Input()` property and have the child component detect value changes?

Comment: [OnChanges](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges) takes an argument [SimpleChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChanges). You would be able to get the new value from there in your first example rather than from `this`.

Comment: Thank you. What about the setter though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular change detection is triggered when the @Input property value changes.

So to trigger change detection in case of an object you could ***pass a copy of the object using spread operator*** as the input.

for eg. `someVar = {key: value}` this is `@Input()` variable, so pass like

```
<app-sample [someVar]="{...someVar}" ></app-sample>
```

`{...VARIABLE}` <- here is the magic

if spread operator won't work use any object deep copying methods like

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how you would do this.

Comment: The angular compiler throws 'Unexpected token' error.

Comment: This is not working. Please provide a working solution or an explanation. I have same question as @Jack above.

Comment: Thanks. It is now clear. However, this does not sound like a good solution as object copy would be created everytime refresh happens - is that right?

Comment: In my case cloneDeep, spread operator nothing is working

state ={skip:0, filter:{op:'asc', filters:[{field:'demo', value:'123'}]}, take:1}

this is my object and when I am doing 

state.filter = <new object>;
state = _.cloneDeep(state);

onchange is not triggered

Answer (score 22):

The [OnChanges](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges) lifecycle hook is triggered when the `@Input` property value changes. In the case of an object, that value is the **object reference**. If the object reference does not change, `OnChanges` is not triggered.

A possible technique to force change detection is to set a new object reference after modifying the property values:

```
this.whatever.value1 = 2;
this.whatever.value2 = 3;
this.whatever = Object.assign({}, this.whatever);
```

The `ngOnChanges` event handler can then be used to monitor the changes:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  for (let propName in changes) {
    let chng = changes[propName];
    let cur = JSON.stringify(chng.currentValue);
    console.log(propName, cur);
  }
}
```

As an alternative, if `@Input` decorates a getter/setter property, the changes can be monitored in the setter:

```
private _param: Object;

@Input() get param(): Object {
  return this._param;
} 
set param(value: Object) {
  console.log("setter", value);
  this._param = value;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzjrbo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: Maybe its a good idea to add a note about why creating new objects instead of changing its properties is not a bad pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
@Input() public param: any;
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    // Do your check here
    console.log(changes.param.previousValue);
}
```

Using changes gets you access to previousValue and currentValue.

Comment: Thanks, it does, but for some reason beyond me our lead forbids the use of ngChanges. That's why I'm trying to use a setter.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution based on Franklin answer:

just create a method which returns the copy of the object, like

```
whateverCopy() {
    return {...this.whatever}
}
```

and pass like

```
<my-component [param]="whateverCopy"></my-component>
```

Comment: Yes, this was the solution I found myself.

Answer (score 1):

You have ref https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges

> The log entries appear as the string value of the power property
> changes. Notice, however, that the ngOnChanges() method does not catch
> changes to hero.name. This is because Angular calls the hook only when
> the value of the input property changes. In this case, hero is the
> input property, and the value of the hero property is the reference to
> the hero object. The object reference did not change when the value of
> its own name property changed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a second @input variable to trigger the chnage detection:

```
export class MyViewComponent  {
  @Input() triggerChangeDetection: [];
  @Input() data: Data;
```

View:

```
<app-mycomponent [data]="data" [triggerChangeDetection]="triggerChangeDetection"></app-mycomponent >
```

on every update to the data object I call:

```
export class AppComponent{

  public data: Data;

  public triggerChangeDetection: [];

  private triggerChangeDetectionToUpdateComponents() {
    this.triggerChangeDetection = [];
  }
```