# ngStyle and value allocation to object

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a component where i need to edit some Styles on another component.
i pass the object to the component by property binding.
the BorderRadius is updating when i declare a new object in .style... But not when i allocate a value to a existing key.

is this a fault in my code? or a bug? Or why is it so?

binding elProp to elementComponent

```
<app-element text="Test4" (click)="selectItem(item.id)" [elProp]="getProperty(item.id)"></app-element>
```

ElementComponent

```
<div
  fxLayout="row"
  [fxLayoutAlign]="property.text?.style?.position"
  style="background-color: rgb(51, 134, 153);"
  [ngStyle]="elProp.style"
  [ngClass]="{ 'selectedItem': elProp.selected}"
>
  {{ elProp?.text?.value }}
</div>
```

input...

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="borderradius" (ngModelChange)="updateStyle()" >
```

```
updateStyle(){
    this.itemProperty.map(el=>{
      if(el.itemId == this.selectedId)
        //  el.style.borderRadius = "20px"; <<< doesn't WORK
        //  el.style['borderRadius‘] = "20px"; <<< doesn't WORK
        // Object.assign(el.style,{borderRadius: "20px"}); <<< doesn't WORK
        el.style = {borderRadius: "20px"}; <<< WORKS
    })
  }
```

model

```
export interface ItemProperty {
    itemId: string;
    selected : boolean;
    color: string;
    border: string;
    text: {
      value: string,
      style: {
        position: string
      },
    };
    style:{
      borderRadius: string;
     // border: string,
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug, this is an expected behaviour from Angular.

First of all, NgStyle is an @input property.
You are passing an Object (elProp.style) to this @input. The problem is when you change property of the object - @input doesn't recognize it as a **new** value, because **object reference is the same**.

Good explanation from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55050549/14493509:

> The OnChanges lifecycle hook is triggered when the @Input property
> value changes. In the case of an object, that value is the object
> reference. If the object reference does not change, OnChanges is not
> triggered.

So

```
el.style.borderRadius = "20px"; // Same object reference -> OnChanges is not triggered
el.style = {borderRadius: "20px"}; // New Object -> new reference -> OnChanges triggered
```

Comment: thanks:) thats the explanation i looking for..